# Linux/Ubuntu: Restricting access to specific USB ports based on username

Tags: ubuntu, usb, libusb, udev

We have multiple test systems connected to a Ubuntu PC through the USB ports, each device is determined by its serial number. When the serial number is not provided, the application defaults to first available port. To be able to use the system each user needs to be a super user.
Considering every USB port is visible to every username in the system, a user can control the other system (unintentionally).
If there is a way to lock/restrict a usb port to a particular user name, the access to devices could be managed better.
Question:
Are there ways to restrict USB ports based on user name ?

I a looking for guidance on possible options to explore further

Answer (score 0):

I think [udev rules](https://linux.die.net/man/7/udev) and Linux groups can solve this problem.

It's not clear exactly what type of USB device you are talking about, and what nodes it creates in your filesystem, and what the permissions of those nodes are.  So this answer might not be *exactly* what you need but I hope it points you in the right direction.

In general, you probably had to add a udev rule to your system to grant the users access to those USB devices.  This is a typical rule I often use on systems I maintain in order to grant permission for all users to use native USB devices with vendor ID 1234:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", MODE="0666"
```

You would save that file in the `/etc/udev/rules.d` folder with a filename like `99-myrules.rules`.

But you don't want to use that rule exactly.  Here are some changes you would need to make:

1. Add a key-value pair to the rule so the rule only applies to one USB device, specified by its serial number.  I [think](https://askubuntu.com/a/165262) it would looke like this:  `ATTRS{serial}=="serial_number_of_one_of_your_devices"`.
2. You should change the MODE to `0660` so it doesn't grant permissions to everyone, but it does grant permissions to users in the right group.
3. Add a GROUP directive that looks like `GROUP="groupname"` to set the GROUP of the file node for that USB device.  Each user on Ubuntu generally has a group of their own, with the same name as the user, so you could use that, or you could create more groups using the standard mechanisms Unix provides to manage user groups.

You can have multiple rules in a single file, with each rule on their own line.  There would be one rule per device.